# getJSON on Sharepoint list stops at 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sharepoint, getjson

```
$.getJSON("urlhere", {}, function(data)
{
     // Other code is commented out, I'm just using the following loop to test.
     for(var a = 0; a < 2546; a++)
          if(a > 995)
               alert((a + 1) + ": " + data.d.results[a].Column2);
});
```

For some reason, I wasn't getting all the things from my list that I needed. So I put in this loop to test it and it stops at 1000 for some reason. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is probably more a problem of the datasource (Sharepoint) than of JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think so, it works perfectly except for the ones over 1000.

Comment: Have you checked the JSON that is returned by the URL manually?

Comment: Yes, I have. The getJSON itself only got 1000. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No, but as I said: It seems to be a problem of Sharepoint. Maybe there is some parameter for it?

Comment: That's what I thought so I looked it up here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp but it doesn't seem like there's a parameter for it. It says the 'data' parameter specifies data to be sent to the server, but doesn't give any examples.

Comment: The parameters are not defined by the protocol, but by the server! So you would have to look into your Sharepoint instance to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'urlForListData' + '?$filter=Building eq \'' + building + '\''`

I found out that you can filter the list for what you need so that it never exceeds 1000, which was much simpler than what I was doing before. Of course, Building is a column in the SharePoint list and building is a variable holding the requested building number.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint only returns 1000 results per "page."  If you look, there should be a "link" element in there near the bottom of the JSON that contains a link to the next 1000 results.

That's how it is when it returns XML, anyway.  Haven't tried JSON, but I'm sure it's similar.

Comment: I switched to SPServices but when I'm done with this project I may come back to this to see how it works with getJSON just so I know.

Comment: I believe the link is called "__next", you could do something like 
if (data.d.__next){
    var url= data.d.__next.ToString()
}

Comment: I forgot about Stack Overflow for a while. As I said, I used SPServices instead. I don't know what to do with this question now though.

Comment: post an answer to your own question with the spservices code and flag it as the correct answer.